# Cartesian to polar interpolation and plot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am an amateur Python user, so please bear with me. I currently have a 200x200 array of radar reflectivity values, with the dimensions corresponding to 1d arrays of x and y values (km) that range from -180 to 180. My goal is to perform a **cyclindrical/polar interpolation** on these data so I can appropriately create a polar plot.

I have done the following, but for some odd reason, **griddata()** does not return any values and I'm not sure why. If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
data = [nan, nan, nan,...    
        10.1, 10.5, nan,..] # 200x200 array

x = [-180, -160,...160,180] # 200 x 1 array
y = [-180, -160,...160,180] # 200 x 1 array

"""create arrays of radius and theta"""
r = np.linspace(0,150,100)
theta = np.linspace(0,360,100)

""" convert r and theta to Cartesian points"""
x = r*np.cos(theta*(math.pi/180))
y = r*np.sin(theta*(math.pi/180))

import scipy as sc
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

"""cylindrical interpolation"""
data_cylin = griddata((x_km, y_km), dbz_2km_2052t,(x,y), method='linear',fill_value=0)
```

which returns

```
data_cylin = [0.0, 0.0...0.0].
```

I have also tried creating a meshgrid of r and theta to use in the interpolation, but that just creates a 3D array for data that is unusable for creating a polar plot.

Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the `200*200` data contains? Is it basically reflactance value for a co-ordinates that is specified by values in `x` and `y`? From what you have there `x` and `y` will have only 19 values total.

Comment: Hi @Prophecies, yes the 200*200 data contains reflectivity values corresponding to specific x and y coordinates. How did you arrive at only 19 values? Just based on the range of the original x,y data and the range of r, theta?

Comment: pls provide a minimal example including actual data that reproduces the problem. Is it possible your nan values are creating issues for griddata()?